# Store large amounts of data in RMS

Tags: java-me, midp, rms

I need to store large amount of data using RMS API through J2ME.

How can I store that multiple-column data, given they must be hardcoded so I need to store those multiple columns and rows data.

How can I do this in this, should I use `struct`s?

Comment: please choose a more descriptive headline!

Answer (score 2):

Well, RMS only allows you to store records that are arrays of bytes. You will have to decide for yourself how a record is stored, and if you want to store your data in a single or in multiple records. If you use the DataInputStream and DataOutputStream classes, you'll be able to read/write Strings, booleans, integers, etc. The [API documentation includes a decent example](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/package-summary.html) of how you can do this.

If you have complex data to store, or a lot of different objects, you may want to create a simple library for RMS I/O, that allows you to pass objects implementing e.g. "Storable" to a library class that writes away your object into RMS.

Answer (score 2):

See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011/best-practice-for-storing-large-amounts-of-data-with-j2me) on exacty the same topic. In the end we bought a commercial BTree imeplementation and extended it to work across multiple record stores.

Answer (score 1):

Has Jeroen said RMS is quite basic. You can only store arrays of bytes. But, though it's basic, it's quite easy implement a more complex memory structure with an index stored in a record store and addressing other record stores containing data.

Have a look to this page :  [Understanding the Record Management System](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/databaserms/)