# Random-access data object in J2ME

Tags: serialization, data-structures, java-me, gtfs

I'm planning to develop a small J2ME utility for viewing local public transport schedules using a mobile phone. The data part for those is mostly a big bunch of numbers representing the times when the buses arrive or leave.

What I'm trying to figure out is what is the best way to store that data. The representation needs to

1. be considerably small (because of persistent storage limitations of a mobile phone)
2. <strike>fit into a single file (for the ease of updating the schedule database afterwards over HTTP)</strike> fit into a constant number of files, i.e. (`routes.dat`, `times.dat`, ..., `agencies.dat`), and **not** (`schedule_111.dat`, `schedule_112.dat`, ...)
3. have a random access ability (unserializing the whole data object into memory would be just too much for a mobile phone :))
4. if there's some library for accessing that data format, a Java implementation should be present

In other words, if you had to squeeze a big part of [GTFS](http://code.google.com/transit/spec/transit_feed_specification.html)-like data into a mobile device, how would you do that?

[Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) seemed like a good candidate for defining data but it didn't have random access.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Just how much data is it, exactly?

Comment: Not sure yet, but my approximations are that it could grow up to 5 MB. Depends on the data storage format too.

Comment: From my initial calculations it was even up to 10 MB, but there is one catch in here - typical citizen doesn't "use" all the lines at every hour of the day and night - he/she uses up to 10 lines. The amount of data decreases dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

Persistent storage on J2ME is a tricky business; see this related question for more general background: [Best practice for storing large amounts of data with J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011/best-practice-for-storing-large-amounts-of-data-with-j2me)

In my experience, J2ME persistent storage tends to work best/most reliably with many small records rather than a few monolithic ones.  Think about how the program is going to want to access the data, then try to store it in those increments in the J2ME persistent store.

I'd generally recommend decoupling your client-server protocol for downloading updates from the on-device storage format.  You can change the latter with every code update, but you're pretty much stuck supporting a client-server protocol forever, unless you want to break older clients out in the field.

Finally, I know there are some people on the [Transit Developers group](http://groups.google.com/group/transit-developers) who have built offline transit apps in J2ME, so it's worth asking for tips there.

Answer (score 1):

I made app like this and I used xml-s generated with php. This enabled us to have a single provider for 3 presentation layers which were:

- j2me app
- website for mobile phones
- usual website

We used xslt to convert xml to html on websites and kXML - very light pull parser to do it on j2me app. This worked well even on very old phones with b/w screens and small amounts of memory.

Besides on j2me there is no concept of file. You have the db in which you can store information.
This is a link to "mobile" website.
http://mobi.krakow.pl/rozklady/

and here to the app:
http://www.mobi.krakow.pl/rozklady/j2me/rjk.jar

This is in polish, but I think it's not hard to figure out what's this and that.

If you want, I can provide you with more help and advice or if this is a commercial product then I think we can figure out something too ;)

Comment: Hi. As I understand, your application does a HTTP request whenever it needs data, thus the actual data is stored in the server.

See, my idea is that the application could have that very same data stored in an 'offline' resource file located in a JAR, making the whole thing faster and cheaper to use.

Comment: The application stores the data it downloads and then you have the option to refresh it. Once again I can see that you don't know much about J2ME - you cannot store data in a jar file(unless it's data stored when you create it - jar is really zip). Because of security reasons jars are unmodifiable on cellphones.
While developing the app we also wanted to make it as cheap as possible, because prices of mobile internet in Poland are rather high(at least they were). This was the cheapest option from those that we considered.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is requirement 2.

Updating 10MB of data just because 4 digits changed somewhere in the middle of the file seems highly inefficient.

Spliting the data into several files allows for a better update granularity that will be well worth the added code complexity.

Real-time public transport schedules are usually modified one bus/train/tram line at a time.

Comment: Hi,

I'm not thinking 'real-time', at least for the J2ME application. Up here where I live, schedules change three-four times a year, and *all* the digits get updated :)

Actually, what I'm trying to achieve is having a non-changing number of files with the data. I updated my original description of the problem a bit to reflect this better.