# Problem in Uninstalling Application from Nokia E-72

Tags: java-me, nokia, midlet, rms

i have created an application which stores lots of **data around 100 mb in rms** and application process on this data

now when i am un-installing application from Nokia e-72 some times it remove application many time it cant remove application

when it cant remove at that time i have to go in control panel --> installed application --> uninstall application.

even i can't able to un-install from there.

some times it hang phone at time of un-installing application.

if i have **less data in RMS** then that app can **removed easily.**

what could be problem and how i can solve this problem??

Comment: Why you use RMS for storing 150 MB size? At what purpose do you want to use of this?

Comment: i have created application in which i am managing lots of customers data around 5000-6000 customer data in xml formate. is there any other way to manage RMS data???

Comment: Yeah man you're not meant to save that amount of data in RMS!  Use the file system or something else, not RMS for 150MB!!

Comment: i am not storing all data in one file i have created rms files at runtime means if there is 1000 customer data i separate them in 100 rms files like cust_1,cust_2,cust_3......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary solution i am un-installing application in following way

first removing all RMS Data from application it self
now when application is without any rms data i can remove it like 
option--> remove

Answer (score 1):

Basically RMS designed for small amount of data. If you want to store huge amount of data means you can store into card or store into database through GPRS. See [this existing discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011/best-practice-for-storing-large-amounts-of-data-with-j2me) same in this forum.

Better option is choose file system(JSR-75). But signing required for accessing the file system. It will be cost.

Comment: thanks bhakki i got it but is there any connection with removing from device??? because if we install app then it must be removed from device... large RMS size may create problem in running application but not in removing..

Comment: do you want to create the RMS?

Comment: no, i just want to remove application which i have installed and which is having bulk data....

Comment: no i even cant uninstall manually.. and same problem i am facing in 5-6  E-72